# Реализация поиска в фрагменте listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, filter

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь реализовать поиск, используя `ListView` в качестве фрагмента. В `MainActivity` `toolbar`.

Код самого `ListView`:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    private ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
    private DbWorker db;
    private ListView listView;
    private String orderBy;

    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
    private SearchView searchView;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity class";
    private static final String SORT_BY = "sortBy" ;
    private final static String SORT_BY_NAME = "name";
    private final static String SORT_BY_CATEGORY = "category";

    public ListViewFragment(){}

    public static ListViewFragment newInstanceLvFragment(final String typeOfSort) {
        final ListViewFragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();

        final Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        args.putString(SORT_BY, typeOfSort);

        listViewFragment.setArguments(args);
        return listViewFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments == null || !arguments.containsKey(SORT_BY)) {
            orderBy = null;
        } else {
            orderBy = arguments.getString(SORT_BY);
        }
    }

    @Override   
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewfragment, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        new DbAsyncTask(v.getContext()).execute();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Contact contact = contactAdapter.getContact(position);

                ChangeContactFragment changeContactFragment = ChangeContactFragment
                        .newInstanceChangeFragment(contact.getContactId(), contact.getContactName()
                                ,contact.getContactPhone(), contact.getContactCategory()
                                ,contact.getContactOrgName(), contact.getDate());
                fTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_in_right);

                fTrans.replace(R.id.fragContainer, changeContactFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment addContactFragment = new AddContactFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_in_right);
                fTrans.replace(R.id.fragContainer, addContactFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                contactAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        };

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       //убрал код, здесь сортировки, работают без проблем.}

    private class DbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Contact>> {
        private Context ctx;

        public DbAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                db = new DbWorker(ctx);
                contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) db.selectAllContacts(orderBy);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in AsyncTask.doInBackground");
            }
            return contacts;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
            contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ctx, contacts);

            listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater lInflater;
private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
private ArrayList<Contact> filteredContactList;
private ContactFilter contactFilter;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.contactList = contacts;
    this.filteredContactList = contacts;
    this.lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Contact getContact(int position) {
    return ((Contact) getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) { //нет проблем }

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (contactFilter == null) {
        contactFilter = new ContactFilter();
    }
    return contactFilter;
}

private class ContactFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint !=null  && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Contact> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Contact contact : contactList) {
                if (contact.getContactName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempList.add(contact);
                }
            }
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = contactList.size();
            filterResults.values = contactList;
        }
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredContactList = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

В итоге поиск не работает. Ввожу в поле данные для поиска, ничего не происходит.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, где ошибка.

Comment: У вас отфильтрованный список - `filteredContactList`, а `getItem` и проч. делаете по `contactList`.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо. Вы правы, возникла путаница.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо в методах  getCount(); и getItem(int position); заменить contactList на filteredContactList